# XPath. Select 'A' tag text BUT only up to specific text value

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML code that I'm reading from a movies web site:

```
<div class="blue">
    Director <a href="http://...">Bobby Farrelly</a>, <a href="http://...">Peter Farrelly</a>. With <a href="http://...>Jim Carrey</a>, <a href="http://...">Jeff Daniels</a>.
    <div class="red">
         page 1
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to separate the director(s) from the actors usign XPath. As you may see

**directors are:** Bobby Farrelly and Peter Farrelly

**actors are:** Jim Carrey and Jeff Daniels

The only way to distinguish directors from actors from this bad formed XML is detecting the string "**. With**" and selecting the A tags up to it.

By using:

```
foreach($r as $result) {
    $tag = $result->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach($tag as $text) {
        $t = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $text->nodeValue));
    }
}
```

I can select the DIV and the text inside the A tags. But this will select ALL the A tags, to get the directors only I need to select only the text inside the A tags **up to the ". With"** string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible xpath :

```
//div[@class="blue"]/a[following-sibling::text()[contains(., "With")]]
```

Above xpath reads: find all `div` where `class` attribute value equals "blue". Then from within each of such `div`, select all `<a>` tag before text node containing text `"With"`.

Output in [xpath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) :

```
'<a href="http://...">Bobby Farrelly</a>'
'<a href="http://...">Peter Farrelly</a>'
```

Comment: Your xpath works perfectly. Actually I did not considered in my question that this kind of xpath will extract - correctly - all the 'directors' without consider the case of more than one director for each movie. I mean, I have 10 movies; it could be supposed that there are 10 directors. But let's say that xpath extracted 11 directors: this means that one movie has 2 directors. The above xpath will not tell me - my fault - what's the movie with 2 directors. How can I use the above xpath to consider the case of 2 directors? I guess I could count the iterations somehow.

Comment: Use xpath that return all movies (f.e `//div[@class="blue"]`), loop through the movies and get directors from each movie using relative xpath (f.e `a[following-sibling::text()[contains(., "With")]]`). You can't accomplish all that with xpath only

Comment: Thanks! Great solution.