# Multiple OR 'contains' conditions

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to extract directors and actors from the following kind of XML

**first case**

```
Directors <a href="">Leslie Greif</a>. With <a href="">Wendi McLendon-Covey</a>, <a href="">Tammin Sursok</a>, <a href="">Jesse Bradford</a>, <a href="http://www.mymovies.it/biografia/?a=141527">Reid Ewing</a>. Genre    <a href="">Commedy</a>
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923678/xpath-select-a-tag-text-but-only-up-to-specific-text-value) answer now I can separate directors from actors by looking for the **'With'** string:

```
.//a[following-sibling::text()[contains(., 'With')]]
```

**second case**

Unfortunately there are cases that there are no actors so there's no 'With' string but only **'Genre'**

```
Director <a href="">Michael Mellon</a>, <a href="">Alexander Rossi</a>. Genre <a href="">Doc</a>
```

So I guessed that the following xpath could flawlessly work:

```
.//a[following-sibling::text()[contains(., 'With') or contains(., 'Genre')]]
```

but this xpath does extract every name up to **Genre** independently if there is or there's not the string 'With'. It does not care about the first condition ('With').

Comment: It would help if you could add a tag or two to your question to indicate what host language you're using to execute your XPath expressions.  Judging from your comment on my answer I'm guessing PHP DOMXPath but only you can confirm for definite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at it the other way around - for the directors you find the first text node that contains *either* of `Genre` or `With`, then extract all its *preceding* `a` elements

```
text()[contains(., 'With') or contains(., 'Genre')][1]/preceding-sibling::a
```

and for the actors you want all the `a` elements between `With` and `Genre` (which may be zero if there's no `With`)

```
a[preceding-sibling::text()[contains(., 'With')]]
 [following-sibling::text()[contains(., 'Genre')]]
```

Comment: Sorry but I tried with the following code inside a loop and your first snippet: `$direct=xpath->query("text()[contains(., 'With') or contains(., 'Genre')][1]/preceding-sibling::a", $result); foreach($direct as $item) {$director = $director.", ".$item->nodeValue;}` but is does'nt match anything.

Comment: @Nicero what is `$result`?  My expression assumes the context is the parent element of the `a` elements and the `With` and `Genre` text nodes, if it's anything else it'll need adjusting to match the structure.

Comment: @Nicero the other thing to note is that the expression will return a list of element nodes (the `a` elements), and in the DOM `nodeValue` doesn't mean what you think it does for element nodes.  If you want the text inside the `a` element then you should use `textContent` instead of `nodeValue`.

Comment: Hi Ian, I will check my code but in the meanwhile I placed your snippets into a xpath tester. Please take a look to [this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e3089c444f89fdb7bd2d87604688c35a). Shoud'nt it return the directors? And [this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/4436099724bce5a42fc40378d05378d2) should'nt return the actors? I really don't understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Nicero in that XPath tester the context would be the ["root node"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node) of the XML snippet, which is a kind of virtual node that acts as the parent of the `div` element.  To take this into account you'd need to add `div/` to the front of the path [like this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/229b879904357ea737c3ca1face8cbf6) - `div/text()[contains(., 'With') or contains(., 'Genre')][1]/preceding-sibling::a`

Comment: @Nicero [and the same applies for actors](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/a94ea960e963b717e72c5f541b3f3514) - `div/a[preceding-sibling::text()[contains(., 'With')]] [following-sibling::text()[contains(., 'Genre')]]`